# Call php variable array name in foreach loop

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I have arrays with the following names:
    $MyMondayClasses, $MyTuesdayClasses, $MyWednesdayClasses, $MyThursdayClasses, $MyFridayClasses

And I have an array for days of the week:
    $days = array('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday');

I want to loop through the days of the week and then run the appropriate array, but I'm not sure how to refer to the variable to make:

```
foreach($days as $value){
    foreach($My{$value}Classes as $ClassKey => $ClassVar){
        some code goes here
    }
}
```

I used to use eval for this sort of thing, but understand that's not best practice.  Anyway, the above code isn't working.

Comment: Why don't you just have one class that you pass the day of the week to?  I presume the days of the week classes will be similar.

Comment: have you considered constructing your `$MyDAYClasses` arrays in another array with the days for indices from the beginning ? e.g. `classes = array('Monday'=> $MyMondayClasses), ...);`  That way when you want to look them up, you can find them easily.

Answer (score 2):

> I have arrays with the following names: $MyMondayClasses, $MyTuesdayClasses, $MyWednesdayClasses, $MyThursdayClasses, $MyFridayClasses

Sounds not very clever.

Why don’t you just have *one* array, with 'monday', 'tuesday' etc. as keys - and then have your data arrays for each day under that key …?

Comment: `Sounds not very clever` sounds very not-clever. I done gone made a grammatical mistake up :-P  (+1)

Answer (score 0):

Does not make sense .. you should use array but if you insist you can try :

```
foreach ( $days as $value ) {
    $name = sprintf("My%sClasses", $value);
    if (! isset(${$name})) { // the boss asked
        continue;
    }
    foreach ( ${$name} as $ClassKey => $ClassVar ) {
        // play some ball
    }
}
```